# Can't install software because Ubuntu thinks my Intel processor is an AMD

Tags: software-installation, cpu

Today I have tried to update Chrome and also to install XnView (photo viewing software) on my desktop machine with an Intel® Core™2 Quad CPU Q6600 @ 2.40GHz × 4. Each time I get a message that I have downloaded the wrong (AMD) version. As I don't get a choice of processor type when I download something is misdetecting my processor.

The actual error message is 'Wrong Architecture (AMD64)'

What can I do?

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: The actual error message is 'Wrong Architecture (AMD64)'  Sorry, I added that after my initial post.

Comment: And what displays the error? AMD64 is the right architecture here, the Q6600 is 64-bit and definitely not Itanium.

Comment: The Chrome update was triggered by my current copy of Chrome, which then passed me through to the Ubuntu Software Center.  I started the XnView install on their Web site and then again was passed to the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Please provide an output of 'lsb_release -a' here. It will show info about your installation.

Comment: The error message appears in the Ubuntu Software Center .

Comment: By the way: just to make sure ... you do understand that amd64 means the architecture NOT that it is an Intel CPU? amd64 means a 64-bit system. i386 a 32-bit system.

Comment: The output of 'lsb_release -a' is too long to post here.   Here is the first part if that helps:  lsb_release -a
LSB Version: core-2.0-ia32:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-ia32:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-ia32:core-3.2-

Comment: @ Rinzwind: I'm not totally sure of whether there is a Linux-specific way of interpreting AMD v Intel. I do know the difference between 32 bit and 64 bit architectures.  As I am not specifying either the manufacturer or the bit count whatever is going on is not directly due to anything I am doing when the install fails. Also, I have installed a fair bit of software (mostly photo processing programs) in the few months since I started using Linux. This 'Wrong Architecture' message is a new one to me.

Comment: AMD released their 64bit architecture before Intel, intel choose ia64 for itanium based processors and licensed use of AMD64 for some of their processors.  So, AMD64 is the standard architecture for intel and amd 64bit processors, outside of some circumstances, ie, Itanium.

Comment: @AlbertInFrance Could you also add the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: While you may be able to run the 32 bit Chrome it is losing support. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/google-chrome-linux-32-bit-discontinued

Comment: uname -a
Linux Acer-Spades 3.19.0-43-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 31 15:46:00 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: It seems you are not upgrading your Ubuntu for long. Try an update and dist-upgrade to the latest 14.04.4 and recheck.

Comment: And every time I try starting the Software Updater I get a message: Failed to download repository information Check your internet connection.

Comment: I tried doing: 
    sudo apt-get update

Got a long list of items finishing with:  

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I'm not keen to go further until I know if this is significant -- it looks like it.